# because angular takes files from a history folder for compilation?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I was working all right until I rebooted my server, the error that throws me makes references to a .history folder of the LOCAL HISTORY extention of vsCode. They are from a very old version of the code, try disabling the extension, deleting the .history folder but still follow the problem and do not let the server go.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use this settings and it should ignore those files.

"local-history.path": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode",
"local-history.enabled": 2